# How Do I add to an ArrayList within a HashMap while iterating

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, hashmap, lwjgl

While following a tutorial series for LWJGL for my file university project, I add game items to the world that have an associated Mesh class,

If I were to add many objects to the world that shared the same mesh, it would be more efficient to associate a list of game items to one Mesh type and then render from there

```
private Map<Mesh, List<GameItem>> meshMap;

meshMap = new HashMap();

     public void addDynamicGameItem(DynamicGameItem dynamicGameItem) {
    numGameItems++;
        Mesh[] meshes = dynamicGameItem.getMeshes();
        for(Mesh mesh : meshes) {
            List<GameItem> list = tempMap.get(mesh);
            if (list == null) {
                list = new ArrayList<>();
                tempMap.put(mesh, list);
            }
            list.add(dynamicGameItem);
        }
}
```

this works perfectly until I try to add new game items to the world while the hashmap is being iterated over, any subsequent calls to addStaticGameItem seems to add the game logic of a new item to the world, but the Mesh is not added properly and thus cannot be seen at all.

here's where the hashmap is called for rendering:

```
Map<Mesh, List<GameItem>> mapMeshes = scene.getGameMeshes();
    for (Mesh mesh : mapMeshes.keySet()) {
        if(mesh.getMaterial() != null) {
            sceneShaderProgram.setUniform("material", mesh.getMaterial());
            Texture text = mesh.getMaterial().getTexture();
            if (text != null) {
                sceneShaderProgram.setUniform("numCols", 
                text.getNumCols());
                sceneShaderProgram.setUniform("numRows", 
                text.getNumRows());
            }
        }
          mesh.renderList(mapMeshes.get(mesh), (GameItem gameItem) -> {
                    sceneShaderProgram.setUniform("selected", 
                    gameItem.isSelected() ? 1.0f : 0.0f);
                    Matrix4f modelViewMatrix = 
                    transformation.buildModelViewMatrix(gameItem, 
                    viewMatrix);
                    sceneShaderProgram.setUniform("modelViewMatrix", 
                    modelViewMatrix);
                    Matrix4f modelLightViewMatrix = 
                    transformation.buildModelLightViewMatrix(gameItem, 
                    lightViewMatrix);
                    sceneShaderProgram.setUniform("modelLightViewMatrix", 
                    modelLightViewMatrix);
                }
        );
    }
```

So how do I properly add new values to a Hashmap list while iterating?

EDIT: this works

```
public void updateMeshMap(){
    if(!tempMap.isEmpty()){
        for(Mesh m : tempMap.keySet()){
            List list = meshMap.get(m);
            if (list == null) {
                list = new ArrayList<>();
                list.addAll(tempMap.get(m));
                meshMap.put(m, list);
            }else{
                list.addAll(tempMap.get(m));
            }
        }
    }
    tempMap = new HashMap<Mesh, List<GameItem>>();
}
```

Comment: You do not seem to be calling `addStaticGameItem` in the `for (Mesh mesh : mapMeshes.keySet()) {` loop at all... So what are you talking about when you say "until I try to add new game items to the world while the hashmap is being iterated over"?

Comment: I call addstaticgameitem from another class when creating new objects and meshes for the world, later on I use the same method to create new game items, except now that the hash map is being iterated over, new items aren't being added,  all previous items are added during class initialisation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually can't add new values to HashMap while iterating. But you may try to create a temporary map `tempMap`, add new items to this `tempMap` and then, after iterating, change your original HashMap (u can use `meshMap.putAll(tempMap)`).

Also check out [HashMap documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)
Where you can find

> The iterators returned by all of this class's "collection view
> methods" are fail-fast: if the map is structurally modified at any
> time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the
> iterator's own remove method, the iterator will throw a
> ConcurrentModificationException.

Comment: I tried exactly this before, and for some reason after calling meshmap.putall(tempmap) where temp map had two new objects in, the length of meshmap did not change and I could still not see the new objects ingame meaning something went wrong with adding the new game item meshes

Comment: You might be adding new entry with key already existing in your map. Then you need to add new values in list on this key. You can check every `put()` as it returns the previous value associated with key, or null if there was no mapping for key or use `map.containsKey(key)`.

Comment: The key being the Mesh, technically the key should already exist becsuse I am adding a new object type that already exists within the hashmap, new gameitem, same mesh, also do you know why I don't get a concurrent modification exception when trying to add items to the hashmap?

Comment: Then you should use `ArrayList<GameItem> gi = map.get(key);` After smth like `if (gi == null) {
         gi = new ArrayList<GameItem>();
         gi.add(myGameItem);
         map.put(key, gi);
    } else {
        if(!gi.contains(myGameItem)) gi.add(myGameItem);
    }` not `put()`. Because HashMap stores unique key-value entries and .put() with same key will overwrite old value

Comment: At the expense of ConcurrentModificationException, as far as I remember, it is the iterator who throws it, that is, something like `Iterator it`. This has historical roots, in Java 1.2 collections and iterators appeared and in those days it was impossible to avoid the **explicit** use of the iterator when iterating through the collection and, accordingly, the error is thrown from the iterator method, which you most likely do not use, so it does not appear to you.

Comment: Are you saying I should replace the addstaticgameitem method with your method, or to use your method when creating a temporary hashmap with new items to be added

Comment: Look if u have a HashMap where u have (k1: l(v1, v2),...) and use put(k1: l(v3)) you will have HashMap (k1: l(v3), ...). Instead in your code where you put, you should get old list, change it with adding new values and then put (second comment), so (k1: l(v1, v2),...)  -> (k1: l(v1, v2, v3),...). And still you need to avoid putting something during iterating over map - using a temp map, for example and change list inside it same way. So you need to change your existing method according to this